# Finding the Jordan / Prejordan Basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}5 & 4 & 3 \\-1 & 0 & -3 \\ 1 & -2 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$

And I want to find the Jordan Basis. I have found the Characteristic polynomial which  is $(x+2)(x-4)^2$, the same as the mimum polynomial and I thus know the Jordan Canonical form.

So far what I have tried:

I first considered $\lambda = -2$ and I found the nullity of this eigen space here to be 1, with an eigen vector $(1, -1, -1)^T$, although I am not sure if this is correct.

Now with $\lambda = 4$, after reduction $T- 4I$ we get:

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4 & 3 \\-1 & -4 & -3 \\ 1 & -2 &-3  \end{bmatrix}

I found an eigen vector $(-1, 1, -1)^T$ but I'm a bit stuck on what to do next? Do I need to find $(T-4I)^2?$ Doing this I found $(0,-1,1)^T$. How does this eigen vector relate to the ones I have already found.

Also how do I go about creating a prejordan basis? I know that once I have one, I can just apply $T-\lambda I$ on the 'lower dimension' basis vectors to get a Jordan basis, but I'm struggling to find this one. Do I just 'guess' any linearly independent vector from my eigen vectors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So there is the generalized eigenspace $\ker (T-4)^2$ in your case you can check that this is all vectors $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\-b\end{pmatrix}$. What you want is a vector in this eigenspace but not in $\ker(T-4)$ The latter you have calculated as being generated by the vector given in the question. So a vector in $\ker(T-4)^2-\ker(T-4)$ is $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.
This is one element of your basis. The next element of your basis is $(T-4)v$ (which with ny choice of $v$ is just the negative of the vector you gave.) These two vectors $v, (T-4)v$ are then a basis for the gereralized eigenspace of $T-4$.